# In GAN network, I got error while trying to transform tensorflow dataset's to range [-1,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

The images in the [TensorFlow Fashion MNIST Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/fashion_mnist) are in range of `[0,255]` and I wish to transform it to the range of tanh function `[-1,1]`, for this I'm using the map function as shown below.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

def scale_images(data): 
    image = data['image']
    return (image - 127.5) / 127.5

ds = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', split='train')
ds = ds.map(scale_images)
```

However it is giving me the error mentioned below.

```
File "<ipython-input-74-665c2cac0d84>", line 8, in scale_images  *
        return (image - 127.5) / 127.5

    TypeError: Expected uint8 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Sub', got 127.5 of type 'float' instead. Error: Expected uint8, but got 127.5 of type 'float'.
```

It works perfectly when I use `return image / 255` to reduce it to range `[0,1]` but it gives error when using the code shown above.

Please tell me how to transform the dataset's range to `[-1,1]`.

EDIT:

For context I'm creating a GAN with [this code](https://github.com/nicknochnack/GANBasics/blob/main/FashionGAN-Tutorial.ipynb) as reference. However I have changed the activation of last layer of generator to tanh. Thus, I also need to change the images to the match the range of tanh output so that my discriminator is trained effectively. So I'm trying to modify the scale_images function to do the same.

Comment: Make sure the image variable has a float data type, it is currently integer which produces the error.

Comment: @I'mahdi `TypeError: Expected uint8 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Sub', got 127.5 of type 'float' instead. Error: Expected uint8, but got 127.5 of type 'float'.` same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `image / 255` but you can not pass `(image - 127.5) / 127.5`, So you can use below tricks:

**Method_1 :**

For going to the range `[-1,1]` from the range `[0,1]`, you can use the simple trick `(num*2)-1` like below:

```
def scale_images(data): 
    image = data['image']
    image = image / 255
    return (image * 2) - 1
```

**Method_2:**

You can use [`tf.cast(image, tf.float32)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast) like below:

```
def scale_images(data): 
    image = data['image']
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    return (image - 127.5) / 127.5
```

Comment: Works in that cell and the following but raises error `ValueError: Layer "sequential_1" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None,) dtype=string>]` in train cell `hist = fashgan.fit(ds, epochs=20, callbacks=[ModelMonitor()])`. The train cell did not raise an error when I was training with return `image / 255`. The first layer is Conv2D(32, 5, input_shape = (28,28,1))

Comment: @Aditya Punetha, adding your full code in your question by editing

Comment: It works without returning label in case of `return image / 255`

Comment: @AdityaPunetha, edited answer, try : `return (image*2)-1`

Comment: @AdityaPunetha, Is Your problem solve?

Comment: That just changed every value to 255 @imahdi, also added context to the ques

Comment: @AdityaPunetha, first scale value of image to [0,1]

Comment: @AdityaPunetha, `method_2` and `tf.cast` can help you?